# Laravel dynamic display file content

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, tail, laravel-echo

I have a terminal that logs on a file linked in my app `/storage/logs/output.log`.

I have no problem displaying it inside my view, the only problem is that I want the content of this file to update dynamically, without doing a `setTimeOut()` every *X* seconds like a `tail -f`.

I thought of using an event system, like `cat`, but I don't know how to manage it.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: You should study how queue job works. There is good explanation in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues) about it. It's not most easiest task but that is the way to do what you want here. You need to learn what are queues, how those work, how to set up and engage those, and then come with concrete question if you face an issue during development. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can check how you can ask question right way to be sure it would attract someone to help you.

Comment: I think that what you want is [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) or anything similar, you want an event based system